# Issues with Adam Lynch's flexible data tables with CSS grid

Tags: vue.js, html-table, resize, scrollbar

I am using Adam Lynch's flexible data tables with CSS grid code. It is a really neat project. https://adamlynch.com/flexible-data-tables-with-css-grid. I have a couple questions on the project.

1. I notice that when I scroll to the right hand side of the column with the horizontal scroll bar, I can no longer resize any of the columns. I have been trying to figure out how to fix this for a while now to no avail.
2. I notice that if I resize one column, I can resize a different column immediately afterward with no problems. However, if I attempt to resize the same column twice consecutively, I cannot drag the separator the second time. This problem does not exist in Firefox, but does exist in Google Chrome.

Comment: I am running version Chrome Version 74.0.3729.157 and Firefox Version 66.0.5

Answer (score 0):

Okay. Found the answers.

Answer to question # 1... Need to explicitly change the overflow property of the table element from the default value 'visible' to 'auto' or 'scroll'.

```
  overflow: scroll;
  display: grid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  min-width: 100%;
  /* These are just initial values which are overriden using JavaScript when a column is resized */
  grid-template-columns: 
    minmax(150px, 1fr)
    minmax(150px, 1.67fr)
    minmax(150px, 1.67fr)
    minmax(150px, 1.67fr)
    minmax(150px, 3.33fr)
    minmax(150px, 1.67fr)
    minmax(150px, 3.33fr)
    minmax(150px, 1.67fr);
}
```

Answer to question # 2...Need to prevent the default behavior of the browser on a mousedown event. I ported this code to Vuejs. In Vuejs, the syntax is `@mousedown.prevent="resizeInit"`